# Django Rest Framework - Serializer Method field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When using serializer method field, the dictionary with Decimals is converted to Integers.

For eg.

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bill_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_bill_details(obj):
        return {'editable': False,
           'final_amt': Decimal('4198.00'),
           'total_amt': Decimal('4198.00'),
        }
```

becomes this:

```
"bill_details": {
    "total_amt": 4198,
    "editable": false,
    "final_amt": 4198
  }
```

Is there any solution to this? I am expecting this:

```
"bill_details": {
    "total_amt": "4198.00",
    "editable": false,
    "final_amt": "4198.00"
}
```

Comment: have you considered not using Decimal  there? And this doesn't give the complete context can you also share the program where this function is used and written.

Comment: @harshil9968 updated the serializer class. I am getting decimals from database which I am processing and adding here. This is just an example to show what I am doing.

Comment: float(2123.00) can you use like this instead of decimal?

Comment: also try to use this format(2313.00, '.2f')

Comment: @harshil9968 I am getting the data from database. Don't want to manually convert them to string.

Comment: you can use this `format(obj.total_amt,'.2f')`

Comment: This seems like a prime example of when you should use a nested serializer.

Answer (score 11):

> Django REST framework 3.0 gives you the option to 
>   [**`serialize decimals as floats`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#decimals-as-strings-in-serializer-data).

Decimals are now coerced to strings by default in the serialized output. You can modify this behavior globally by using the `COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING` settings key.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING': False
}
```

Or modify it on an individual serializer field, using the `coerce_to_string` keyword argument.

```
# Return `Decimal` instances in `serializer.data`, not strings.
amount = serializers.DecimalField(
    max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2,
    coerce_to_string=False
)
```

The default JSON renderer will return float objects for `un-coerced` Decimal instances. This allows you to easily switch between string or float representations for decimals depending on your API design needs.

**UPDATE**

If you want to just round it to produce a string with 2 decimal precision to display to the user, you can do

```
def get_bill_details(obj):
    return {
       'editable': False,
       'final_amt': '%.2f' %  Decimal('4198.00'),
       'total_amt': '%.2f' %  Decimal('4198.00'),
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

> You can make it **DRY**, By using a **custom
>   JSONEncoder** class.

Create a `DecimalEncoder` class, inheriting [**`json.JSONEncoder`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)

```
from decimal import Decimal
import json

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return '%.2f' % obj
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Now Use this class inside `get_bill_details` method

```
def get_bill_details(self, obj):
    bill_detail = {
        'editable': False,
        'final_amt': Decimal('4198.00'),
        'total_amt': Decimal('4198.00'),
    }
    return json.loads(json.dumps(bill_detail, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

Comment: Which version of DRF are you using?

Comment: make sure you are importing Decimal from right place `from decimal import Decimal` , I tested it with `SerializerMethodField` and it is working, I am getting value `"total_amt": 4198.0`

Comment: I want `"4198.00"`, not  `4198.0`

Comment: the main problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849246/django-rest-framework-serializer-method-field/51248367#comment65063663_38849246 I don't want to convert manually many decimal values.

Comment: @DmitriyM You have to do it manually, I don't think there is an inbuilt for your requirement, but you can make it DRY, By using a custom JSONEncoder class. check my `UPDATE 2` section

Answer (score 3):

You can use new Serializer in SerializerMethodField like so:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BillDetailsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    editable = serializers.BooleanField()
    final_amt = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=15)
    total_amt = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=15)

class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bill_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = '__all__'

     def get_bill_details(self, obj):
         data = {...} # your logic
         field_serializer = BillDetailsSerializer(data=data)
         field_serializer.is_valid() # this serializer must always valid
         return field_serializer.data
```

I think it is more clear and everyone can undestand what fields have bill_details

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use different serializer for bill_details, then,

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from decimal import Decimal

class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bill_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_bill_details(obj):
        amount_field = DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
        final_amt = Decimal('4198.00')
        total_amt = Decimal('4198.00')
        return {
            'editable': False,
            'final_amt': amount_field.to_representation(final_amt),
            'total_amt': amount_field.to_representation(total_amt),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's become integer because `4198.00 == 4198`, if you like to keep `00`, you should use `str`

if you like only 2 ints come after a point you can use format ( like what harshi said `format(obj.total_amt,'.2f')` but the result should be a string ( as like you said in your expected result)

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bill_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_bill_details(self, obj):
        return {'editable': False,
           'final_amt': str(Decimal('4198.00')),
           'total_amt': str(Decimal('4198.00')),
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849246/django-rest-framework-serializer-method-field/51248367#comment65063663_38849246

Answer (score 1):

```
class BillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bill_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('__all__')

     def get_bill_details(obj):
         return {'editable': False,
             'final_amt': format(Decimal('4198.00')),
             'total_amt': format(Decimal('4198.00')),
          }
```

please try to use format()